# Star systems forming when large gravitational force is applied

Tags: supermassive-black-hole, star-systems, stellar-dynamics

As far as I'm concerned, most star systems in our galaxy are traveling in fairly circular paths around the black hole at the center.

Hypothetically, if a large gravitational force pulled star systems closer to the center of our galaxy would binary star systems result? If two stars of different masses were travelling in a centripetal motion around the center of our galaxy, and they were pulled towards the center (which *i think* would result in two different accelerations completely) could a situation result where two stars collide or join into a system? What is the most probable event to happen in this situation besides two stars not approaching eachother?

Comment: To clarify, what do you think is the significance of the black hole to the motion of the stars? Also Its not clear why you mention the rotation of the galaxy at all.

Comment: I think this is a good question (if I'm interpreting it correctly) it's just worded poorly. What I believe you intended to ask (and correct me if I'm wrong) is what the collision rate would be if the stellar density of our galaxy were much higher (due to stars orbiting much closer to the center than they do now). Would there be a chance of physical collisions? Would binary stars form with any frequency by happenstance? Is that what you were going for?

Comment: Sorry guys. I was trying to ask what would be the result of the motion of the stars when being "pulled in closer" to the center of the galaxy in a hypothetical situation, I just couldn't word it well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Most binary stars are believed to have formed together as they condensed out of a common rotating dense cloud of gas and dust. A few more form when, coincidentally, two are ejected from a cluster at the same time at very low speeds.

In high density stellar systems, close flybys tend to disrupt wide binary systems.  This happens because energy from the flyby can be exchanged with the binary and sometimes that increases the binary orbital energy from negative to positive values (escape regime). So, if you increase the density of the galaxy (by increasing the gravitational source at the center), it is likely to reduce the number of binary systems via close encounters.  However, it would take a tremendous increase in density from the mean galactic density for this to begin to be non-negligible.